# R: create a new folder using the given path

Tags: r, directory, stringi

I would like to create a new folder(`newPack`) in the parent folder(`pathPos`) of a given path(`path`) using R functions.

```
path <- "/m/home/user/unix/R/3.5/stringi"
newPack <- "stringr"

pathPos <- stringi::stri_locate_last_fixed(path, '/')[-1]
pathNew <- paste(stringi::stri_sub(path, 1, pathPos), newPack, sep = '')

dir.create(pathNew)
```

I could achieve this using the above code, but I strongly feel there is a better option of doing it. If you know of any, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe with `?basename`.

Comment: I assume you meant `dirname()`. Thanks, it avoids usage of `stringi` functions: `stri_locate_last_fixed`, `stri_sub` in the above snippet. i.e., `pathNew <- paste(dirname(path), '/', newPack, sep = '')`

Comment: How about `setwd(path); setwd(".."); dir.create(newPack);`

Comment: @Prradep Oops! Right, `dirname`.

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks, I could use that but it is more tedious to change the working directory thrice :(

Answer (score 12):

```
path <- "/foo/bar/baz"
newfolder <- "qux"
newpath <- file.path(dirname(path), newfolder)
print(newpath)
# "/foo/bar/qux"
dir.create(newpath)
```

Or, skipping the intermediate creation of `newpath`:

```
path <- "/foo/bar/baz"
newfolder <- "qux"
dir.create(file.path(dirname(path), newfolder))
```